# Mudar a imagem da logo quando a partir da classe CSS navbar-inverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Dentro do meu HTML on page eu tenho uma `div` de `header` que muda no css ao rolar a página até determinado pixel. Eu consigo trocar as cores da barra e dos textos mas não consigo trocar a imagem da logo

Como eu faço para trocar a imagem assim que o `navbar` muda para `navbar-inverse`?

Qual é o javascript pra isso?

```css
.menu-right {float: right;}
.navbar-inverse { margin-bottom: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0; -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out; transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out; border: none; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); padding: 15px 0; }
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a { color: #fff; display: block; -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; }

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li {-webkit-transition: all 400ms linear; -moz-transition: all 400ms linear; -o-transition: all 400ms linear; -ms-transition: all 400ms linear; transition: all 400ms linear;}

.navbar-toggle { padding: 4px 6px; font-size: 16px; color: #fff;}
.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active { outline: 0;}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle { background: #08b4da; border: none;}
.navbar-nav {margin: 0;}
.scroll-fixed-navbar {padding-bottom:0;}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {background-color: transparent;}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand {margin-left: 0;}
.navbar-brand { height:auto;}

.scroll-fixed-navbar { padding: 10px 0; background-color: #FFF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
.scroll-fixed-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {color: #333;}
.scroll-fixed-navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.scroll-fixed-navbar .navbar-nav > li.active > a,
.scroll-fixed-navbar .navbar-nav > li.active > a:hover {color: #00a8d6; }

.navbar-toggle { position: relative; float: right; background-color: transparent; padding: 10px; margin: 13px 30px 13px 0; border: none; color: #fff; border: 2px solid #fff;}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar { background-color: #fff;}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand  {color: #FFF; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 700; padding: 0;}
.scroll-fixed-navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand  {color: #1a1a1a; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 700; padding: 0;}
.text-logo {margin-top: 5px}
.text-logo i {margin-right: 10px;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-inverse {background-color: #FFF; padding:0;}
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {margin-left: 15px; color: #1a1a1a; margin-top: 15px;}
    .menu-right {float: none;}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {color: #1a1a1a;}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover { color: #00A8D6;}
    img {display: block; margin: 20px auto;}
    .section {padding: 70px 0;}
    .main-point {margin-bottom: 40px;}
    .video-container {margin-bottom: 40px;}
    .img-thumbnail {margin: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <!-- Start Logo / Text -->
              <img src="img/logo-cecom.png" height="50px" align="left" alt="logo da central dos Compradores"></img>

              <!-- End Logo / Text -->
          </div>
          <!-- Start Navigation -->
          <div class="navigation navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#banner">Início</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#intro">Benefícios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#testimonials">Depoimentos</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#faq">Dúvidas</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Amigo edite sua resposta e coloque todo seu CSS e o JS que está usando só com o html não da para te responder precisamente. Mas uma coisa que eu adiante é que apenas com Classes CSS vc não consegue trocar uma tag IMG, o máximo que da para fazer é ter duas IMGs e ocultar uma e mostra a outra no scroll, ou então usar a IMG como background IMG e trocar esse background no scroll

Comment: Entendi. Pode ser qualquer solução. Apenas preciso trocar a logo quando o header descer. Acho que deixar uma imagem como background e depois trocar já serve. Tentei isso mas não funcionou. Não sei se fiz certo também.

Comment: Vc não faz o script? Vc quer trocar a imagem quando o usuário rolar a tela pra baixo, ou quer trocar a imagem quando a tela for mais larga ou menos larga?

Comment: Qual versão do Boostrap vc está usando??

Comment: Bootstrap v3.2.0. Quero que a imagem troque quando o cara rolar o página.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu entendi você já tem um script que muda a cor ao rolar da página, então é acrescentar na sua lógica o código:

```
document.getElementById("minhaDiv").src="suaImagem.jpg";
```